# Xcode 11 isn't showing object library in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I have installed Xcode 11 and as apple suggest in https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views link I opened the object library but there are only three option one for code snippet, second for media and the third one is for color but not seeing object library in the + icon that is placed on the top right corner

1) tried to open the object library as apple suggest.

please see this screenshot

[image]

should show object library

Comment: You need macOS 10.15 Catalina installed to enable the object library.

Comment: anyone seeing this behavior running Catalina?  I am having it now

Comment: actually to follow up on the comment above if I create a new project I see it but I don't see it on a SwiftUI project from a previous beta

Comment: I see this with new project in BigSur 11.5.2 only snippet/media/color available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mo Reza Farahani's comment
"You need macOS 10.15 Catalina installed to enable the object library". After  installed macOS 10.15(Beta) it is working fine.

[image: After update you can see object library]

Comment: Hello...I have the same problem and running OS catalina 10.5.2... but still don't see all the elments just my personal snippets

Comment: me too MacbookAir M1 BigSur 11.5.2

Answer (score 21):

If you are coding in SwiftUI , please remember to keep canvas editor open and then click on the plus button of object library . If your canvas editor is close , 
selecting object library (cmd + shift +l) won't show the object list in the library .

Comment: That is an absurd requirement

Answer (score 2):

It is not working on existing projects, which is already created in Xcode10.14 or less.You have to Create new project to see all these options!

Answer (score 1):

In your xcode 11 please press the + sign in the top of the xcdoe. It will open the dialog box with the object library.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. To enable the content library you need to add the Canvas view to your workspace. Find Canvas in the Editor menu or Option + Command + Return.

Answer (score 0):

If you have syntax errors in the view you're working on, you won't see it either. Make sure you have no errors and try again.